# How to compare two 2D arrays item by item in lexicographic way?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, comparison

I know how to compare two arrays by first item, second item and so on. For example `[ 2  3 10  9  6 -1]` is higher than `[ 2  3  2 10 -1 -1]`. I need a vectorised way that works with a couple of 2D arrays, like so:

```
a = [[ 1  3 10  9  6 -1]
 [ 5 12  6  5  4  3]
 [ 2  9  5  6 -1 -1]
 [ 2  9  4  8 -1 -1]
 [ 1  5 12 11  9 -1]
 [ 0 12  9  6  5  3]
 [ 4  9 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 1  5  9  6  2 -1]
 [ 2  9  5 12 -1 -1]
 [ 1  8 11  9  5 -1]]
```

against

```
b = [[ 2  3  2 10 -1 -1]
 [ 1  3 12  6  4 -1]
 [ 0 10  9  7  6  5]
 [ 2  6  4 12 -1 -1]
 [ 1  6 12 11 10 -1]
 [ 1  3 12  8  6 -1]
 [ 4  9 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 0 12  6  5  4  2]
 [ 0 12 10  9  6  5]
 [ 1  8 11  9  5 -1]]
```

How can I get indices of items of first array that win, lose or end in a tie? An expected output is:

```
{'win': [1, 2, 3, 7, 8],
 'lose': [0, 4, 5],
 'tie': [6, 9]}
```

Comment: can a code in javascript help you?

Comment: It has a numpy tag which relates my question with Python specifically. Im going to edit my tags in this case.

Comment: I've got a solution already, this is a voluntary share.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I was able to implement a method that works as expected:

```
def lexcompare(a, b):
    diff = a - b
    rows, cols = np.where(diff!=0)
    idx = np.r_[True, np.diff(rows).astype(bool)]
    checks = diff[rows[idx], cols[idx]] > 0
    wins, loses = rows[idx][checks], rows[idx][~checks]
    tie = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(diff)), rows[idx])
    return {'win': wins, 'lose': loses, 'tie': tie}
```

Output:

```
{'win': array([1, 2, 3, 7, 8], dtype=int64),
 'lose': array([0, 4, 5], dtype=int64),
 'tie': array([6, 9])}
```

Comment: Why have you written something this complicated, when a linear traversal of each row could've done the trick?

Comment: write your own solution then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even if it may not be very *numpy-esk* a simple manual row-wise comparison does the trick just fine:

```py
import numpy as np


def lex_comp(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> dict:
    d = {'win': [], 'tie': [], 'lose': []}
    
    for i, (a_i, b_i) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
        for a_ij, b_ij in zip(a_i, b_i):
            if a_ij > b_ij:
                d['win'].append(i)
                break
            if b_ij > a_ij:
                d['lose'].append(i)
                break
        else:
            d['tie'].append(i)
    
    return d


a = np.asarray([
    [1, 3, 10, 9, 6, -1],
    [5, 12, 6, 5, 4, 3],
    [2, 9, 5, 6, -1, -1],
    [2, 9, 4, 8, -1, -1],
    [1, 5, 12, 11, 9, -1],
    [0, 12, 9, 6, 5, 3],
    [4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [1, 5, 9, 6, 2, -1],
    [2, 9, 5, 12, -1, -1],
    [1, 8, 11, 9, 5, -1]
])

b = np.asarray([
    [2, 3, 2, 10, -1, -1],
    [1, 3, 12, 6, 4, -1],
    [0, 10, 9, 7, 6, 5],
    [2, 6, 4, 12, -1, -1],
    [1, 6, 12, 11, 10, -1],
    [1, 3, 12, 8, 6, -1],
    [4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [0, 12, 6, 5, 4, 2],
    [0, 12, 10, 9, 6, 5],
    [1, 8, 11, 9, 5, -1]
])
    
results = lex_comp(a, b) # {'win': [1, 2, 3, 7, 8], 'tie': [6, 9], 'lose': [0, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: `lex_comp` is 4 times slower than `lexcompare`. That's why I'm looking for a vectorised solution (`for` loops are slow).

Comment: Depends on the dimensionality of the input matrix (N, K), but yeah I've tested against that as well. If K is big, `lex_comp` performs better in comparison - if N is big, `lexcompare` performs better.